# SSIS job taking 'hours' -- All Executions report not adding up or showing errors -- where to find cause?

Tags: ssis, report

New to SSIS but not ETL tools. Colleague left me steaming pile scripts to repair.

One script is apparently taking 'hours' every day. When I look at 'durations' of steps in the Standard Reports in SQL Managemenet Studio (SSISDB > Projects > Reports > Standard > All Executions) --- it oddly shows all green/ successes (but only half the sub jobs have run) --- and the durations of all the steps are all like a few minutes each. So where are the "hours and hours"? What step is getting hung up and why? No idea.

Of course if I ran the project/ package at a local level, I will get more information and see what's getting hung up, but so far, exporting packages from SSIS to Visual studio seems to not save connection passwords and other things (super) --- I have them, but this guy didn't use "project wide" connections, he wrote the same one in each package like 40 times ---

Comment: Everything you need should be in the logs / reports. No need to run it locally. It's a pain, introduces network traffic, is not a true representation and doesn't give you much more information. There is a package 'total run time' in the top level report (displayed in seconds). If that doesn't represent 'hours' then I guess your investigation is over. Although you may want to check the SQL Agent job (I assume) that runs it in case that is the actual thing that takes hours.

Comment: It's also a pain that project don't save passwords but it stops people saving free text credentials all over the place. Or at the very least forces them to actually consider security. The easiest workaround is to only ever use windows authentication (assuming your source and target databases support it). In fact if you are only using SQL Server and your packages are full of SQL Logins then that is another measure of how bad the original developer was... My advice is get over it now because you will continue to uncover this stuff.

Comment: I understand the connection thing -- that's fair but its methods are not intuitive, and I get encrypting passwords -- but like I said, some repeated connections are project level, some are package level (where the same one is used repeatedly). I'm new to SSIS but that seems bad. I ended up finding out what step of the script was hanging up by analyzing potentially what SQL query was taking all day on the server - that showed me. A full table scan & update of 70 million records daily. Records that never retroactively change so --- why?? Bigger the ego, the steamier the pile I'm afraid.

Comment: To clarify, I see the 'full duration' of the package in question (which in turn calls dozens of other packages) --- which approaches infinity (I have to stop it). I couldn't see what sub-step/ ongoing step was taking forever, which is odd, but perhaps that's either a limitation, or specific configuration, of SSIS. Certain sub-steps or ongoing steps aren't logged, apparently, in this case. Found it through direct SQL transaction logs but I'm lucky "that" was the piece that was hanging, though it probably usually is (hellish query).

Comment: It sounds like you have a project-level rewrite on your hands.

Comment: That much is clear. It was nothing important - just the company financials. I'm definitely on a tangent here but this is evidence as to why a non-tech businessman shouldn't hire a sole developer who builds his 'genius' script in an ivory tower that no one reviews for years -- meh. Always happy for the help on here

Comment: I feel your pain

Comment: A visit to thedailywtf.com might make you feel better... or worse